# What are the pros and cons of using UILabels for the icons in the app instead of UIImages?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel, truetype

Basically I am trying to use a ttf file to render images for my icons in the app.

I know few pros of this approach like:

- Its lightweight (app size reduction)
- overlaying colors is easier
- dynamic sizing can be done using font size
- treating images like fonts.

Cons can be:

- Proper naming conventions required for other devs to understand what image is being used, since images
  copied from ttf file to Xcode will be shown as a special character( ex: "?")

Apart from this can anyone let me know if it's really feasible to replace the png images used for icons with the UILabel implementation.

Any reference articles will help !

So far i have looked into these:

https://medium.com/nyc-design/font-icons-in-swift-4-4c173fc52d0c

https://medium.com/@deerchaudhary/svg-or-ttf-icons-in-ios-swift-4-0-without-using-any-third-party-library-4622deaf0939

Comment: For the naming you could use a struct with static let properties to use the character. Eg : static let heartWithArrow = "K". So in xCode you just use constants : MyImageCharacter.heartWithArrow.

Comment: Yes. This definitely can be done. But i want to know more on using UILabels as icons. Is it beneficial ?